# ionic v3 Disable emoticons option from keyboard and restrict to input the emoticons

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

How to restrict emoticons option from keyboard, so that user will not be able to input the emoticons in HTML input field?

Comment: Good luck with that. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `(keypress)="onChange($event)"` on the Input tag. And then when an emoji is wrote down, you could remove it on JavaScript like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (keypress)="onChange($event)" />
```

JavaScript:

```
text:any;
onChange(e) {
  this.text = this.text.replace(/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])/g, '');
}
```

It should replace the emojis.